# Multi-selection values from ListBox to paste in different cells in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, copy-paste

I have a listbox with the option of multi-selection and I need to paste the values selected (maximum 5 values) to 5 different cell in sheet named grid_2 (each value need to be in a different cell the cell are **Grid_2.range("A1:E1")**.
I manage to paste the 1st value on the cell, however the others repeat the last selection.

[image: the result I am getting]

I am trying to fix my code before paste the 5 values selected in the cells, but for now I am able only to have 1 unique value (the first selection from listbox in the cell "A1") and the value on the cells "B1", "C1" etc will bill the same as the last selection. However, I need each selection to be populated in 1  cell and not have duplicate values or repeat the same value.

```
  Public Sub Select_Bene_Click()
    
     Dim addme As Range, addme1 As Range, addme2 As Range
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, Ck As Integer
    
        Set addme = grid_2.Range("A1")
        Set addme1 = grid_2.Range("B1")
        Set addme2 = grid_2.Range("C1")
        Ck = 0
    
             For x = 0 To Me.List_Bene.ListCount - 1
             If Me.List_Bene.Selected(x) Then
             Ck = 1
    
             If addme = "" Then
             addme.Value = Me.List_Bene.List(x, 0)
    
             Else
            addme1.Value = Me.List_Bene.List(x, 0)
    
             If addme1 = "" Then
             addme1.Value = Me.List_Bene.List(x, 0)
    
             ElseIf addme1 <> "" Then
             addme2.Value = Me.List_Bene.List(x, 0)
    
                End If
              End If
       End If
    Next x
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You say that your new to VBA.  Are you using [RubberDuck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/tag/v2.5.0)?  You should watch this series [Excel VBA Introduction Part 1 - Getting Started in the VB Editor](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on YouTube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the code you have in `Public Sub Select_Bene_Click()` to the code below. Hopefully that should do the trick

```
Public Sub Select_Bene_Click()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")   '<- Change sheet name
    Dim iItem As Long, iC As Long: iC = 0
    Dim aRng As Variant: aRng = Array("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1")     '<- Make sure range is what you want
    
    For iItem = 0 To Me.lstTesting.ListCount - 1                        '<- Change the name of listbox
    
        If Me.lstTesting.Selected(iItem) Then                           '<- Change the name of listbox
            oWS.Range(aRng(iC)).Value = Me.lstTesting.List(iItem)       '<- Change the name of listbox
            iC = iC + 1
            
            If iC > UBound(aRng) Then Exit For
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You went a little off script but I like this better than my own code.  Nice work!!

Comment: @TinMan: Thanks. I think our concept is the same, just different ways of approaching it :)

Comment: @Zac your code is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Zac Would it be possible to make the code more dynamic? I mean  is there a way for  the excel user be able to choose 15 or even more variation of a name and it is automatically placed in a cell on line 1? Now the excel user can choose only 5 **("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1")** would it be possible not to limit a number?

Comment: Yes. But as this query has already been answered and your query is an extension to the original question, If you start a new one query and post the link to it here, I'll try and get something for you there

Answer (score 1):

It simpler to increment a counter and use  `grid_2.Range("A1").Cells(1, counter)` to target your range.

```
 Public Sub Select_Bene_Click()
    
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, c As Long
    
    Set Target = grid_2.Range("A1")

    For x = 0 To Me.List_Bene.ListCount - 1
    
        If Me.List_Bene.Selected(x) Then
            c = c + 1
            Target.Cells(1, c).Value = Me.List_Bene.List(x, 0)
            
            If c = 5 Then Exit For
        End If
        
    Next x
    
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly. I will use the Zac's code because I may need to add more cells in the Array in the future, so I believe it will be more easy. Thank you so much for your time.